# How to remove duplicates based on a certain column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table like this

```
fid name   date
---------------------
1   John1  2020-10-08
1   John2  2020-10-08
1   John3  2018-06-04
2   Tom1   2019-10-08
```

I want to preserve the row for each `fid` that has the most recent date. However, if there are multiple, keep only 1 (any of them is fine). So the final result should end up like

```
fid name   date
---------------------
1   John1  2020-10-08
2   Tom1   2019-10-08
```

Does anyone know how to do this in SQL Server? I use v14 (2017) if that matters.

Problem is if I group by `fid` and do `Max(date)`, I get 1 record per `fid`, but then when I left join on it to get the other columns it gives me back 2 records since the most recent date shows up twice.

Comment: First it sounds like you want to remove rows from your table ("remove duplicates"), then it sounds like you merely want to select rows without duplicates ("to get the other columns"). Which do you want? `DELETE` or `SELECT`?

Comment: Not delete original data, just get a query that doesn't include the ones I want gone. So I want to select.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use a deletable CTE along with `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fid ORDER BY date DESC, name) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

The above logic will assign `rn = 1` (i.e. spare) the record with the most recent date, per group of `fid` records.  Should two records with the same `fid` also have the same latest date, then it spares the earlier name.

Comment: Note that I want to just select, not delete any actual data.

Comment: @omega: Then replace `DELETE` with `SELECT *` (or rather the columns you want to select).

Comment: @omega Then use the same CTE but do `SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1`